# Change video input of a video capture card on a web application

Tags: javascript, video, webrtc

I have a [Dazzle video capture card](http://www.pinnaclesys.com/en/products/dazzle/dvd-recorder-hd/). It has two video inputs: RCA and S-video. On a web application I need to be able to choose between this two video inputs. I've been looking through the [Media Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API), but I haven't found anything that helps me to get this done.

#### Edit

I'm able to list the devices, but this card is shown as a single device. I need to change the video input of this card.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getMediaDevices` API to first list available devices and initialize `getUserMedia()`

If you use adapter.js

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio:true,
    video: {
        deviceId: {exact: DeviceId}
    }
  })
```

if you don't use adapter.js

```
constraints: {
    audio: {optional: [{sourceId: DeviceId}]},
    video: {optional: [ {sourceId: DeviceId} ]}
}
```

have a look at [demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/)

Comment: I'm able to list the devices and choose one. The problem is that a single device has two video inputs and I need to change between those.

Comment: are you getting `stream.getVideoTracks()` two video tracks for a single stream via Dazzle video capture card input?